# A list of all abbreviations used in dictionaries

Tags: abréviations, dictionnaires

Let's say you are using a proper French dictionary (I use http://atilf.atilf.fr/). For an entry of any typical word, naturally you would find many abbreviations, e.g. “*subst. masc.*”, “*p. ext*”, etc. (I am taking the first word of that dictionary here). I would like to know whether there is a list of all these abbreviations expanded (either in general or for this dictionary in particular).

Comment: Any good dictionary should explain them in its preamble, but I can’t find them on the TLFi website.

Comment: [The CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/) has an usually more reliable TLFi, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @[Édouard](/u/2414/%C3%89douard) for going through it.
I think this link might be useful for those struggling like me. This is an [archived copy of wordreference.com/fr/Abbreviations-French.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507002514/wordreference.com/fr/Abbreviations-French.aspx).

This is the [current WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/english/abbreviationsWRD.aspx?dict=fren) list of dictionary abbreviations (FR/EN).  It draws from Collins.