# Abréviations utilisées dans le Trésor de la langue française

Tags: abréviations, dictionnaires

Où peut-on voir une liste des abréviations utilisées dans le *Trésor de la langue française* ? Elles ne sont ni sur le site du le site du [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/) ni sur le site d'[ATILF](http://atilf.atilf.fr/).

---

Where can I find the abbreviations used in the *Trésor de la langue française*?
I have already read [A list of all abbreviations used in dictionaries](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7381)

For example, I could not locate an explanation on [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/) for  « **dés.** », which I only encountered subsequently [on Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/souiller): la désinence. I can infer that « préf » means « le préfixe ».

> [[Source:]](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/enrayer) Étymol. et Hist. 1680 « ouvrir dans un champ le premier sillon » (Rich.). Dér. de raie* au sens de « sillon tracé par la charrue »; préf. en-*; **dés.** -er.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ce [site](http://www.languefrancaise.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=11703) recense un certain nombre d'abréviations utilisées dans le TLFi sur la base d'observations collectives. Il est fait aussi mention d'une liste disponible sur le CD-Rom au moment de la publication du TLFi...

Et dans le milieu de la page, on trouve un [lien vers ce document](https://www.fichier-pdf.fr/2014/08/27/abreviations-tlf/abreviations-tlf.pdf) qui contient les photos de la liste des abréviations dans la version papier.

Answer (score 1):

On peut aussi les trouver dans des documents disponibles sur [cette page](http://www.atilf.fr/spip.php?rubrique77) de atilf.fr., (voir [ce lien](http://atilf.atilf.fr/tlf.htm) à l'onglet *Abréviations* du haut) en plus des [*abréviations des dictionnaires scientifiques et techniques*](http://stella.atilf.fr/TLF/TLFBib2.pdf) et celles des [*études fréquemment citées*](http://stella.atilf.fr/TLF/TLFBib1.pdf). De plus avec [ce lien](http://www.atilf.fr/tlf-etym/), on trouvera sous la rubrique *Bibliographie* (du menu de gauche) 4235 notices bibliographiques auxquelles on fait sommairement référence dans les sections portant sur l'étymologie.

Dans un lien présenté dans l'[autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17185), on trouve un lien vers un article intéressant permettant de comprendre certaines des limites de la restitution électronique de cette œuvre ; voici directement ce lien : Charles Bernet, « [Le TLFi ou les infortunes de la lexicographie électronique](https://journals.openedition.org/mots/1052) », *Mots. Les langages du politique*, 84, 2007.

Answer (score 0):

Peut-être un lien plus direct de la [documentation officielle en ligne](http://atilf.atilf.fr/scripts/mep.exe?CRITERE=ABREVIATIONS_A;ISIS=isis_tlfi.txt;MENU=menu_tlfi;OUVRIR_MENU=0;ONGLET=tlfi;OO1=2;OO3=-1;ISIS=isis_tlfi.txt) d'ATILF pour les abréviations.

Cette page cite en effet un document scanné, mais vous avez surtout accès à un index en ligne.