# Comment lire le TLFi

Tags: abréviations, dictionnaires, tlfi

Il existe heureusement une liste des abréviations utilisées dans ce dictionnaire, mais ce n'est pas tout ce qui est nécessaire. Certaines choses comme la division d'une définition en sous définitions se comprennent assez bien sans explication ; cependant, il existe de nombreux symboles en début de ligne qui sont sans explication et aussi des listes d'exemples qui se prolongent de définition en définition. Il existe donc un certain code de lecture qui n'est pas pris en compte. Je ne trouve rien sur ce sujet. Est-ce qu'un guide à la lecture du dictionnaire existe ? Comment y accéder ?

De plus, dans de nombreux cas, les titres des œuvres citées sont amputés de certains de leurs mots, ce qui les rend méconnaissables assez souvent, d'autant plus souvent que moins initié on est à la littérature. Une connaissance des titres aussi précise que possible n'est pas à négliger bien que ce ne soit que des titres, comme cela permet déjà de situer de quoi et de qui il est question. Ces formes raccourcies ne sont pas listée avec le dictionnaire. Est-ce qu'une liste existe ? Où est-elle ?

Comment: [Possibly related](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17180/abr%c3%a9viations-utilis%c3%a9es-dans-le-tr%c3%a9sor-de-la-langue-fran%c3%a7aise)

Comment: @PapaPoule The abbreviations are not the problem since you find their list on the first page (Accueil Abréviations Crédits FAQ   Contact).

Comment: As-tu lu la réponse de user3177 et documents liés ?

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Les noms d'auteur tronqués sont dans les abréviations (flaub., maupass., montherl., …) ; pas la question ; en ce qui concerne les oeuvres on trouve ceci en utilisant le lien «…misfortunes… » :
« Le Trésor étant un dictionnaire de culture largement fondé sur un corpus, sa version informatisée **aurait dû comporter une liste complète des œuvres citées**. Grâce à l’informatique, il **aurait été possible**, de surcroit, de déceler des  […]. ». Il y a aussi le cercle rouge puis les listes d'exemple à travers plusieurs définitions (pas de trace de tout cela).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*La présentation variable des exemples (citations)*

> « [...] des listes d'exemples qui se prolongent de définition en
>   définition. »

Le *Trésor de la langue française* (TLF) est un dictionnaire publié en 16 volumes de 1971 à 1994 ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr%C3%A9sor_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise)). Dans le tome I, hormis quelques exceptions, les exemples (citations) sont numérotés et « détachés » ([Radermacher](http://www.atilf.fr/IMG/pdf/These_Radermarcher_Ruth_2004.pdf) 2004, à la p. 441) du texte alors que dans le dernier volume ils sont toujours liés à la définition (*Ibid.* à la p. 407) ; c'est à partir du tome V que les citations connaissent une double présentation et que les citations commencent majoritairement à être présentés directement après la définition et sous une forme plus courte et qu'inversement les exemples détachés deviennent minoritaires (*Ibid.*,  à la p. 408 note 29 citant Goosse 1994 : 158). Dans un échantillon on a pu établir qu'en début d'ouvrage les citations contiennent 37 unités lexicales alors que dans le tome XVI il ne comptent plus que 22 mots comparativement à une moyenne totale de 25 mots pour le Grand Robert 1985 (*Ibid.*, à la p. 416). Le TLF compte davantage de citations que les autres dictionnaires (*Ibid.*, à la p. 437) et la nature des sources change au fil de la rédaction (textes techniques, journalistiques par opposition aux textes littéraires) pour se démarquer de celle des autres dictionnaires (*Ibid.*, à la p. 437, 438, 439 ; conclusions à lire en parallèle avec les idées du projet primitif présentées dans la [préface](http://www.atilf.fr/IMG/pdf/La_Preface_originale_du_TLF.pdf) du tome I de Paul Imbs de 1971, par exemple à la p. 8 : « La mise en valeur des  exemples par une typographie relativement coûteuse permet de lire les articles de ce dictionnaire sans incursion dans la partie métalinguistique,  qui ne servira de béquille qu’à ceux qui en éprouvent le besoin ou le plaisir ». ; ou à la p. 50). Au fur et à mesure une place plus grande est accordée aux constructions syntaxiques et à la syntagmatique (*Ibid.*, à la p. 430 et ss.). Les exemples du TLF « sont des phrases complexes qui se veulent délibérément distinctes de l’usage le plus commun. En matière d’exemples, l’objectif du TLF est diamétralement opposé à celui d’un dictionnaire d’apprentissage. L’exemplification dans le Trésor est tout le contraire de la phrase banale, qui serait d’une utilité immédiate pour une personne apprenant la langue » (*Ibid.*, à la p. 426.).

---

En résumé (pour plus de détails on lira l'exceptionnelle et fascinante analyse des exemples au TLF dans la thèse *Le Trésor de la Langue Française. Une étude historique et lexicographique* de [Ruth Radermacher](http://www.atilf.fr/IMG/pdf/These_Radermarcher_Ruth_2004.pdf), aux pp. 383-441 : cliquer *en savoir plus...* au bas de [cette page](http://www.atilf.fr/spip.php?rubrique77)) on doit conclure que **la numérotation et le détachement des exemples** qu'on trouve surtout dans la première partie de l’œuvre ne relève que de la présentation et des objectifs fixés par les rédacteurs et **n'a pas de signification particulière.**

---

*Les codes de couleurs et les signes conventionnels*

[image]
<sup><sup>*Vedette [élevage](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9levage) au TLFi (© 2012 - CNRTL) sur cnrtl.fr*</sup></sup>

Ce qui est en **jaune** correspond à la définition ou au sens ; en **orangé** on a les domaines (*économie rurale, oénologie*) ; en **vert** on identifie des regroupements significatifs de mots (syntagmes, locutions, cooccurrence, éléments en collocation).

[Ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17185), on avait identifié une numérisation des abréviations du TLF qui comporte une section sur les signes conventionnels employés. Malheureusement elle se revèle peu utile pour comprendre l'interaction entre le tiret (−) et le losange plein (♦) :

[image]

Chez *Robert* ([1](https://pr.bvdep.com/demo/AidePR/Pages/pdf/abrevs.pdf), [2](https://studylibfr.com/doc/4327467/tableau-des-signes-conventionnels-et-abr%C3%A9viations)) le *losange plein* sert de **subdivision** séparant, pour un même sens, des nuances de sens ou d'emploi alors que le tiret sert à séparer des nuances de sens déterminées par les contextes, les emplois ou les expressions. On ne peut certifier que ce soit aussi le cas au TLF ni s'il y aurait hiérarchie entre l'un et l'autre mais ça peut servir d'indication. Il est plus important de s'attarder à l'économie d'un article et de voir dans l'exemple présenté plus haut que le sens dans le domaine de l'économie rurale ainsi que les nuances de sens par métonymie et par analogie sont regroupés sous le sens A (*art d'élever des animaux domestiques*).

---

En résumé on n'a pas toutes les informations mais on peut aisément déduire la valeur des codes de couleur de la version du TLFi au cnrtl et s'inspirer des valeurs des signes conventionnels que l'on trouve dans d'autres ouvrages pour dire que le tiret et le losange sont au moins des **subdivisions** à l'intérieur d'un même sens.

---

*Les noms d’œuvres tronqués*

Dans une autre [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/33671) on a identifié une liste de 4235 notices bibliographiques que l'on peut scruter ([ici](http://www.atilf.fr/tlf-etym/), voir *Bibliographies* à gauche) pour identifier un nom d’œuvre partiel. Autrement si on n'y trouve pas l'œuvre en question (Balzac, **Curé vill.**, 1839, p. 60, par exemple) on peut consulter la page wikipédia de l'auteur qui contient souvent une [chronologie de ses oeuvres](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honor%C3%A9_de_Balzac#Chronologie_des_%C5%93uvres) et si la date correspond on trouvera facilement ; autrement une recherche plein texte (FF : ctrl-f) dans la page avec le début du nom de l'œuvre permettra souvent de l'identifier (ici, 1841, [*Le curé de village*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Cur%C3%A9_de_village), publié en feuilleton en 1839). Autrement une recherche directement dans un moteur de recherche de « Balzac, Curé vill. 1839 » (sans guillemets) sera sans doute utile...

Answer (score 1):

Ceci est une toute petite partie de la réponse ; elle fournit la clé aux symboles nécessaires pour la *lecture de l'étymologie*. Le code se trouve en cliquant « **entrer dans la base** » puis « **aide à la lecture** » au lien « [etym](http://www.atilf.fr/tlf-etym) ».

**Signes conventionnels**
* : placé après un mot renvoie à ce mot dans le TLF(i).
 
* : placé avant une forme indique que cette forme est restituée par conjecture.
 
**+** : placé devant une entrée du dictionnaire indique qu'il s'agit d'un ajout à la nomenclature du TLF.
 
**§** : signifie : paragraphe. 
**[ ]** : (crochets encadrant du texte) placés dans une citation, contiennent une intervention de l'auteur de l'article dans le but de faciliter la compréhension de la citation. Voir par exemple, s.v. farcin (Ja ne luy [à celui qui porte une améthyste] prendra trenchesuns [« colique »], Ne farcin ne estranguiluns [« esquinancie »]).
 
**[...]** : indique une coupure dans le texte cité.
 
**Ø** : placé devant le nom d'une source signifie : le mot ne figure pas dans cette source.
 
**=** : placé devant le nom d'une source signifie : trouvé et lu dans une source secondaire (ouvrage, dictionnaire, base de données comme Frantext, Google Recherche de Livres, etc.), mais contrôlé sur la source primaire. Voir par exemple, s.v. bestialement (JobGregF, page 365, § 78 = TL) ; s.v. darwinisme (Fée, Darwinisme, page 5 = Google, Recherche de Livres).
 
**in** : placé devant le nom d'une source signifie : trouvé et lu dans une source secondaire (ouvrage, dictionnaire, base de données comme Frantext, Google Recherche de Livres, etc.), mais non contrôlé sur la source primaire. Voir par exemple, s.v. darwinisme (Delage, Structure, Table analytique, page 871, in Gallica).
 
**<** signifie : provient de.
**>** signifie : passe à.

**PS** On peut supposer pour l'instant que l'usage de l'astérisque dans le corps de l'entrée a la même signification que dans l'étymologie.