# Les sigles « TLFi » et « CNRTL » sont-ils interchangeables pour désigner le dictionnaire etc. ?

Tags: dictionnaires, acronymes

Les sigles *TLFi* et *CNRTL* sont-ils interchangeables pour désigner le dictionnaire ; *CNTRL* est-il une variante orthographique acceptable du deuxième ?

Comment: Notez que TLFi et CNRTL ne sont pas des acronymes: un acronyme est un sigle qui se prononce comme un mot ordinaire et sans épeler chaque lettre (ex: Sida, ONU, OTAN, etc.). J'ai essayé avec TLFi, j'ai postillonné... https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronymie

Comment: Attention, lorsqu'on cherche un mot dans le dictionnaire connu sous le sigle de TLFi, le lien qui apparaissent contient le sigle CNRTL.  Comme ceci: https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/[mot recherché]. Dans la mesure où le site lui-même utilise cette adresse, je ne vois pas de mal à utiliser cette espèce de synecdoque pour le dico en soi. Evidemment, CNTRL est une erreur d'ortographe, très facile à faire, et moi je le fais assez souvent quand je ne me relis pas.

Comment: En Espagne, ils ont la Real Academia Española, qui fait un dictionnaire qui s'appelle Diccionario de la lengua española.  On dit l'un ou l'autre pour dire la même chose.

Comment: @Lambie En France, on a l'Académie française qui fait le dictionnaire de l'Académie. Si tu cites leur dictionnaire, tu peux dire *Dict. de l'Académie* ou *Académie française*, c'est sensiblement la même chose que le cas espagnol. En revanche, le CNRTL n'est pas l'auteur du TLFi, ce n'est que l'un de ses éditeurs. On ne va pas citer une phrase de Proust en l'attribuant à Gallimard. Tu es d'accord avec ça ?

Answer (score 3):

Sur le site, on trouve [23](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=cntrl) fautes d'inattention concernant le CN**RTL** (<strike>CN**TRL**</strike> ressemble à la touche [*ctrl*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ctrl) avec un *n* de plus... ), le *Centre National de **R**essources **T**extuelles et **L**exicales*, que l'on [présente](https://www.cnrtl.fr/accueil/presentation.php) par ailleurs ainsi :

> Créé en 2005 par le CNRS, le CNRTL fédère au sein d’un portail unique,
> un ensemble de ressources linguistiques informatisées et d’outils de
> traitement de la langue.
>  Le CNRTL intègre le recensement, la
> documentation (métadonnées), la normalisation, l’archivage,
> l’enrichissement et la diffusion des ressources.
>  La pérennité du
> service et des données est garantie par l’adossement à l’UMR ATILF
> (CNRS – Nancy Université), le soutien du CNRS ainsi que son
> intégration dans le projet d’équipement d'excellence ORTOLANG.
>
> [ CNRTL ]

---

Dans un grand nombre de cas, ces fautes sont doublées d'une incompréhension et d'un emploi métonymique d'un sigle (fautif dans certains cas on vient de le voir) pour signifier un quelconque *dictionnaire*, or :

> Le **TLFi** est la version informatisée du **TLF**, un dictionnaire des **XIX<sup>e</sup>**
> et **XX<sup>e</sup>** siècles en 16 volumes et 1 supplément qui contient : **100 000**
> mots avec leur histoire, **270 000** définitions, **430 000** exemples.
>
> [ [ATILF](https://www.atilf.fr/ressources/tlfi/) ]
>
> Le Trésor de la langue française informatisé, version informatisée du
> ***TLF***, est en accès libre sur le site du TLFi et du Centre national de ressources textuelles et lexicales (CNRTL).
>
> [ [ATILF](https://www.atilf.fr/publications/ouvrages/ouvrages-publies/tresor-de-la-langue-francaise/) ]

Le TLFi est l'une des ressources du [portail lexical](https://www.cnrtl.fr/portail/) du site du CNRTL ; le CNRTL est adossé à l'[ATILF](https://www.atilf.fr/laboratoire/presentation-francais/#historique) : « L’ATILF (Analyse et Traitement Informatique de la Langue Française) est un laboratoire de recherche en sciences du langage. Cette unité mixte de recherche (UMR 7118) a deux tutelles : le Centre national de la recherche scientifique (CNRS) et l’Université de Lorraine (UL). ».

Comme on l'a vu précédemment, le CNRS a créé le CNRTL, dont le site web héberge entre autres la version informatisée du TLF comme nous venons de le voir.

Le [CNRS](https://www.cnrs.fr/fr/le-cnrs), le Centre national de la recherche scientifique, créé en 1939, « est un organisme public de recherche pluridisciplinaire placé sous la tutelle du [ministère](https://www.enseignementsup-recherche.gouv.fr/) de l’Enseignement supérieur, de la Recherche et de l’Innovation » [de la République française, faut-il le mentionner]. Sa mission : « Identifier, effectuer ou faire effectuer, seul ou avec ses partenaires, toutes les recherches présentant un intérêt pour la science ainsi que pour le progrès technologique, social et culturel du pays. »

---

Le *Trésor de la langue française* (TLF) original, [chef-d'oeuvre](http://www.gallimard.fr/Catalogue/GALLIMARD/Tresor-de-la-Langue-Francaise-C.N.R.S.-Gallimard) chez [Gallimard](http://www.gallimard.fr/searchinternet/advanced/(fcollection)/TRESOR+LANGUE+FRANC%3A%3ATr%C3%A9sor+de+la+Langue+Fran%C3%A7aise+-+C.N.R.S./Gallimard?collection=402&SearchAction=OK), conçu par [Paul Imbs](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Imbs) et dirigé par [Bernard Quemada](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Quemada) de 1977 à 1994, dispose de son sujet sur plus de vingt-trois mille (23000) pages en 16 volumes et commande un certain respect qui à son tour invite un bref rappel de son histoire, et ça tombe bien le CNRTL nous en propose justement un :

> Le Trésor de la Langue Française informatisé (TLFi), est la version
> informatisée du Trésor de la Langue Française (TLF), dictionnaire des
> XIXe et XXe siècles en 16 volumes. En voici, pendant plus de quarante
> ans, les grandes étapes :
>
> **1957** : Le recteur Paul Imbs a pour mission de remplacer le Littré tombé dans le domaine public par une œuvre entièrement originale tant
> par sa structure et sa conception que par ses fondements.
> **1960** : Il fonde le Centre de recherche pour un Trésor de la langue française (qui deviendra l’INALF) avec pour mission de réunir la
> documentation, d’assurer la rédaction et la publication du TLF. Un
> vaste ensemble documentaire informatisé bibliographique,
> lexicographique et textuel est constitué. Ce dernier fonds, source
> essentielle de l’illustration en exemples des articles du
> dictionnaire, constitue également la base de données textuelles
> françaises, Frantext, mondialement diffusée.
> **1964** : Date du dernier texte saisi pour le XXe siècle. Les rédacteurs du TLF disposent désormais en permanence d’une source
> d’exemples d’une ampleur et d’une valeur inestimables.
> **1971** : Publication du premier tome.
> **1994** : Publication du seizième et dernier tome du TLF.
> **1990-1991** : Lancement de la première étude d’informatisation du TLF dans les locaux du laboratoire nancéien de l’Institut National de
> la Langue Française (INALF – CNRS), devenu aujourd’hui laboratoire
> ATILF Analyse et Traitement Informatique de la Langue Française
> (laboratoire associé au CNRS et l’Université de Lorraine).
> **1992** : Acquisition des bandes de photocomposition des tomes 9 à 16 et premiers essais d’informatisation du tome 14 au laboratoire.
> **1993** : Début des travaux au service informatique, un prototype fonctionne sur le volume 14.
> **1995** : Colloque international à Nancy « Autour de l’information du Trésor de la Langue Française ».
> **1996** : Traitement des archives de photocomposition des tomes 9, 10 et 14 à 16 par un prestataire.
> **1996-98** : Constitution de l’archive informatique pour les tomes 1 à 8 par un prestataire. Traitement des archives de photocomposition
> des tomes 11, 12, 13 au laboratoire.
> **1998** : Consultation en accès libre sur le site de l’ATILF, d’une maquette comprenant les tomes 9, 10 et 14 à 16.
> **1999** : Consultation en accès libre, sur ce même site, d’une maquette comprenant le tome 16.
> **2000** : Relecture et vérification des balises de la totalité des tomes par un prestataire. Amélioration du logiciel :
> hypernavigation.
> **2001** : Achèvement des travaux : intégration des corrections, vérifications….
> **2004** : Le cédérom du Trésor de la Langue Française paraît en novembre chez CNRS Éditions

---

On y réfère dans les sources primaires du français moderne à l'[Académie française](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/les-dictionnaires-du-francais-moderne) :

> *Trésor de la Langue Française Informatisé (TLFi)*, Nancy, CNRS, ATILF (Analyse et traitement informatique de la langue française), UMR
> CNRS-Université Nancy.

*Le bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, Boeck/Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>) qui renvoie souvent familièrement au « *Trésor* » y réfère de la manière suivante en bibliographie :

> *Trésor de la langue française. Dictionnaire de la langue du XIX<sup>e</sup> et du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle.* P., Éditions du Centre
> national de la recherche scientifique, puis Gallimard, 1971-1994, 16
> vol.

La BDL réfère au *Trésor de la langue français informatisé* (TLFi) dans au moins une [rubrique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=5259) etc. ([1](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/34510),[2](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/37828),[3](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/17180))

---

La version du TLFi hébergée sur le site de l'[ATILF](http://atilf.atilf.fr/) comporte la mention suivante :

> *La présente ressource est produite et diffusée par l’ATILF à des fins de consultation pour l’enseignement et la recherche, à l’exclusion de
> toute exploitation commerciale. La citation d’un extrait de la
> ressource au sein d’une publication scientifique est autorisée sous
> condition de porter la mention suivante :*
>
> *TLFi : Trésor de la langue Française informatisé*, http://www.atilf.fr/tlfi, ATILF - CNRS & Université de Lorraine.

Son FAQ traite aussi de « la version du TLF sur le CNRTL [...] ». Le [site web](https://www.atilf.fr/) de l'ATILF héberge par ailleurs, à l'image de celui du CNRTL, un ensemble de projets et ressources.

---

- Le [*Trésor de la langue française informatisé*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr%C3%A9sor_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise_informatis%C3%A9) (TLFi), la
  version informatisée du [*Trésor de la langue française*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr%C3%A9sor_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise) (TLF),
  est en accès libre sur le site du [TLFi](http://atilf.atilf.fr/tlf.htm) [ATILF] et [sur le site] du [*Centre
  national de ressources textuelles et lexicales*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/) (CNRTL).
- Le dictionnaire publie son 16<sup>e</sup> tome plus de 10 ans avant
  la création du CNRTL.
- On écrit **CNRTL** et non <strike>CNTRL</strike>.
- Le CNRTL désigne essentiellement ici un centre de ressources dont le site web présente un portail : un mot apparaissant directement à la suite de l'hyperlien « https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ » au portail lexicographique est un mot faisant partie du contenu du TLFi (en accès libre sur ce
  site).

[image]

[image]

---

Il s'ensuit que *non*, *TLFi* et *CNRTL* ne sont pas des sigles interchangeables. Le premier désigne un dictionnaire informatisé, le second est un centre et l'un de deux sites web hébergeant ce dictionnaire parmi d'autres ressources. D'autre part il n'y a aucune variante orthographique du sigle CNRTL ; on trouve parfois (10%) la faute <strike>CNTRL</strike>.

Comment: Est-ce qu'il est envisagé "d'achever" le XXe siècle 1965-1999 ?

Comment: @Personne Malheuresement, je ne crois pas : « Avertissement : la rédaction du TLF est terminée depuis 1994 et la plupart des contributeurs ont quitté le laboratoire. Il n’a pas vocation à être mis à jour. Cette ressource, qui ne fait pas l’objet d’une veille lexicographique, est donc close « en l’état ». Il est donc tout à fait naturel que les définitions qui s’y trouvent ne rendent pas compte des évolutions de la société. » ([ATILF](http://atilf.atilf.fr/tlf.htm))

Comment: La recherche d'un terme donne: cnrtl.fr/definition/[mot]. Les lettres CNRTL sont là. Par ailleurs, la faute d'ortographe, c'est moi. Il est très facile lorsqu'on tape ces lettres, de les renverser.

Comment: @Lambie *de les **inverser*** je pense.

Comment: @jlliagre CNRTL  a) GRAMM. Mettre dans la position inverse à la précédente, **changer l'ordre, modifier en permutant les éléments**.  **Synon**. intervertir, **inverser**, retourner. Renverser les termes.

Comment: Renverser l’ordre des lettres, les tordre, en pétrir la matière visuelle et sonore, c’est aussi traiter les mots comme des choses :https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-01421472/document Il suffit d'ajouter l'ordre. Mais c'est pinailler. Il serait plus utile de dire quelque chose sur le fond et pas sur la forme. Mais bon, tu as décidé de me critiquer sans relâche....

Comment: @Lambie Sur le fonds ? On te dis de ne pas citer le doigt mais ce qu'il montre, et tu persistes à citer le portail et pas le dictionnaire.

Comment: @jlliagre Mais non, je donne (pas je cite) le site internet. C'est tout. Je n'y vois aucun mal. A chacun son truc. "**On** me dit?" [ha ha]. C'est plutôt on m'exige [etc.]

Comment: @Lambie Oui, ce n'est pas très grave de faire cette erreur, beaucoup l'ont déjà faite ici, dont moi il y a longtemps. En revanche, quand un modérateur a modifié ma réponse pour mettre le bon nom, je n'ai pas rejeté sa modification, j'ai été content d'apprendre quelque chose, je suis allé me renseigner sur l'histoire de ce dictionnaire et depuis, je met bien TLFi quand je le cite.

Comment: @jlliagre Régarde le paragraphe qui commence: Le CNRTL ne fait pas de distinction.  C'est un exemple parmi d'autres. https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Discussion_utilisateur:JackPotte/2015 Je ne suis pas d'accord que cela soit une erreur. Ça c'est simplement ton opinion. Moi, j'ai la mienne. Laissons cette histoire.

Comment: @Lambie Oui, c'est un exemple d'une personne qui se trompe comme beaucoup. L'une des raisons est que le TLFi est le dictionnaire proposé par défaut par le CNRTL. Je m'étonne quand même que quelqu'un qui a fait des études supérieures comme toi, dans une université française qui plus est, fasse peu cas de la citation exacte de ses sources, ce qui est un forme de mépris pour les auteurs originaux d'un travail monumental comme le TLF. Tu ne ferais sûrement pas la même erreur avec une citation de la RAE trouvée sur un portail, par exemple Yahoo!, que tu attribuerais à Yahoo! sur Spanish Language...