# L'emploi du mot « Trésor » pour référer au « Trésor de la langue française » (dictionnaire, informatisé) etc. ?

Tags: lexique, abréviations, dictionnaires, fréquence-utilisation

Dans *Le bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, Boeck/Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, 2007) on compte dans les 100 premières pages (sur 1600) 25 emplois du mot « Trésor » en italiques (*Trésor*) pour référer au *Trésor de la langue française* (avec évidement une [notice](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/46594) [bibliographique](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/46599) complète à la fin de l'ouvrage).

- Est-il plus courant de référer à la version imprimée ou informatisée
  avec le mot « Trésor » ou avec le sigle *TLF(i)* ou autrement ; l'un
  ou l'autre est-il préférable ; est-ce ici une particularité du *LBU* ?
- Le mot « trésor » est-il ici surtout un mot significatif ou le
  premier mot du nom de l’œuvre (abréviation) et y a-t-il un usage à l'effet de
  préférer l'un ou l'autre quand on réfère sommairement à un
  dictionnaire etc. dans un texte ?

Comment: Difficile question, mais puisque Trésor peut être ambigu, j'imagine que TLF(i) est plus précis.

Answer (score -1):

Mon trésor,

Trésor peut être ambiguë si :

- Il n'est pas présenté (assez régulièrement)
- Il pourrait s'agir de différents trésors.

TLF(i) et TLF semblent des alternatives courtes et claires au "Trésor de la langue française" pour nommer ce qui en définitive est un dictionnaire.
Je fais ici le paralèlle entre l'usage trésor et celui de "framework" (en anglais ducoup). Tous deux sont des termes vague à conotation positive et je suppose ce qui à poussé Grevisse et Goosse à préférer Trésor plutot que TFL. Ces braves gens ne cherchent alors plus tant à référer au TFL avec une certitude absolue qu'ils ne cherchent à l'associer à quelquechose de positif voir rare, précieux.

je ne connaissait pas le TFL jusqu'à ce jour, et ne sais donc pas de quel nom il est coutûmier.

Mes salutations