# Les abréviations ; que signifie « p. » dans le TLFi ?

Tags: abréviations, tlfi

« P. » signifie « page » en tant qu'abréviation et dans le TLFi cet emploi est normalement utilisé ; cependant on la trouve  dans de nombreuses autres expressions  dans ce même ouvrage et il est évident qu'il ne s'agit plus du mot « page » ; dans la liste des abréviations pour le TLFi il ne figure à l'entrée « p. » pas autre chose que « page » et « paginé » ;

- P. anal. _ P. métaph. et au fig. _ p. ell. _ P. ext. _ P. méton.

[L'enc.libre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/P#Vie_pratique) ne donne rien de plus que « page ».

Je rend cette abréviation par la préposition « par », cela au vue d'une logique plus ou moins apparente (elle ne l'est certes pas pour tout le monde) et je traduis les formes ci-dessus comme suit ;

- par analogie, par métaphore et au figuré, par ellipse, par extension, par métonymie, …

1/ Peut-on confirmer qu'en rapport avec le TLFi cette abréviation soit la bonne ?

2/ Est-ce une abréviation propre au TLFi seulement ou bien est-ce une abréviation généralement utilisée ?

3/ Existerait il d'autres mots abrégés par « p. » dans le TLFi ?

Answer (score 3):

Une [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17185) à une question antérieure réfère aux abréviations de la version papier où l'on trouve une équivalence plus spécifique que « page, paginé » quand on a « p. » avec certains termes :
[image]

Il s'agit bien de la préposition *par*, du moins dans ces cas. Autrement on l'a aussi dans « p. et ch. » pour *ponts et chaussées* et dans le *p.* de « p.-q.-parf. », *plus-que-parfait*.

Answer (score 2):

> 3/ Existerait il d'autres mots abrégés par « p. » dans le TLFi ?

Pour le savoir il suffit de consulter la  liste des abréviations utilisées dans le TLFi à la lettre « P ».

La « bible » du rédacteur (Le *Lexique de règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie nationale*) donne plusieurs abréviations « p. [un mot aussi abrégé] » où « p. » est mis pour « par », et une où il est mis pour « petites » (p. capitales). Mais seul il ne peut être mis que pour « page ». Même chose dans [*orthotypographie*](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-I/abreviations-02.html).

Comment: Quand à la lettre « p » on ne trouve pas « par », on peut être sûr d'y trouver n'importe quoi d'autre dont on aura besoin  alors ?

Answer (score 0):

Comme la question que j'ai posée s'est trouvée essentiellement résolue vers la fin de sa formulation j'ajoute cette solution.

Cette abréviation est apparemment celle de « par » comme on la trouve dans ce dictionnaire d'abréviations générales : [melting mots](https://meltingmots.com/search.php?q=p.). Donc c'est une abréviation généralement utilisée et non particulière au TLFi. Je n'ai pas la moindre idée sur des possibilités supplémentaires.