# Is -at a common noun suffix?

Tags: lexique

I was listening to a podcast and heard the word "anonymat" for the first time - I understood it in context but had to look it up to see the spelling, and was surprised. I would have expected the word for anonymity to be more like "anonymité". I have never seen a noun of this particular form.

I'm just trying to learn to recognize this suffix pattern - if it is a pattern - so that I can correctly parse words like it when I hear them.

What other words have a similar form to "anonymat"?

Examples in english of words like anonymITY would be animosITY, possibilITY, culpabilITY, etc. Is *-at* similarly a suffix for making nouns, or *anonymat* just a one-off?

Comment: E.g. _assassinat_, _prolétariat_, _patriarcat_, _sultanat_; cognate with English _-ate_, from Latin _-atus_. But the use of suffixes may not be the same between the two!

Comment: Oh wow I've never heard *assassinat* either. Again I would have expected it to just be a complete cognate, *assassination* since *-ation* is such a common french word form anyway and so many such words are the same between English and French. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Michaelyus Please do not answer in comments. You really should repost what you wrote as a real answer.

Comment: You can just look it up. [Anonymat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anonymat): “From anonyme + [-at](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-at#French)”. Obviously there are more complete reference (but less easy to read), e.g. [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-at).

Comment: Ah, and that page has a link to [this list of words](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:French_words_suffixed_with_-at), perfect. So, yes, it is a common suffix. "denotes an action or a result of an action".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a common enough suffix.

The French *-at* is cognate with English *-ate*, from Latin *-ātus*, which is the Latin perfect passive participle (or from the Latin *-ātum*, which would be the supine). That also means *-at* in French has the same root as the verbal past participle *-é*; but of course the two are used very differently.

The venerable TLFi has a [whole entry on *-at*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-at), which splits the senses up into different headings and some examples of each. Note the English "cognate" may use different suffixes.

> **I.− Le dér. indique une manière d'être en relation avec le sens de la base qui désigne toujours une personne.**
>
> **A.−** Le dér. désigne une dignité, une fonction et plus vaguement un comportement (permanent ou passager, l'état d'une ou de plusieurs pers.).

E.g. Fr. *émirat*, *palatinat*, *sultanat*, *voïvodat* - compare English *emirate*, *palatinate*, *sultanate* but *voivodeship*.

Fr. *inspectorat*, *patriarcat*; compare these with English *inspectorate* but *patriarchate* vs *patriarchy*, which bears a split in English along semantic lines.

The "behaviour" category is probably the most likely to have a different English suffix; you already have Fr. *anonymat* vs Eng. *anonymity*, and I'd say Fr. *assassinat* vs Eng. *assassination* (although false friend alert: it's more likely to be equivalent to Eng. *murder/homicide*, depending on the specifics) is another good example.

> **B.−** Le dér. est un nom coll. désignant un groupe de pers. exerçant la même fonction ou ayant le même comportement, le même mode de vie.
> **C.−** Le dér. désigne un système, une organ. soc., jur., etc. :

Compare Fr. *prolétariat* to Eng. *proletariat* (note the *-at* rather than *-ate*, being a 19th century loan from French into English), versus Fr. *syndicat* vs Eng. cognate *syndicate*, but by extension *trade union*.

> **D.−** P. méton. Le dér. désigne le lieu où s'exerce la fonction (la dignité) ou le temps qu'elle dure.

This is an extension of A, more or less, although TLFi do put Fr. *juvénat* here; although *juvenate* is attested in English, *juniorate* seems to be the preferred term in the Roman Catholic church in the Anglosphere.

> **II.− Le dér. désigne un produit industr. ou le résultat concr. d'une action.**
>
> **A.−** Produit chim., pharm., etc.

There is a plethora of scientific terms here, this being a productive suffix in the scientific world within many European languages. Fr. *substrat* vs Eng. *substrate*,  Fr. *distillat* vs Eng. *distillate*, Fr. *filtrat* vs Eng. *filtrate*.

Note though how Fr. *hydrate* uses *-ate* instead, with the same spelling as English *hydrate*; chemical nomenclature for substances in French requires *-ate*.

> **B.−** Plus gén., résultat d'une action.

Fr. *lysat* vs Eng. *lysate*, Fr. *infiltrat* vs Eng. *infiltrate*, but only in its noun form.

Then you have lexemes like Fr. *crachat*, which is pretty transparent to a French speaker, but doesn't have a cognate in English, and would just be a *gob of spit* in English if being familiar or *sputum* for a more elevated register. Similarly, Fr. *odorat*, which would simply be *sense of smell* in English.

Comment: Quick clarification - what is "Le dér." in a french dictionary context?

Comment: "Le dérivé", the derivative, i.e. the noun that results from appending suffix *-at* to a root. See https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17180/abr%C3%A9viations-utilis%C3%A9es-dans-le-tr%C3%A9sor-de-la-langue-fran%C3%A7aise for common abbreviations.